# Check for DB2 locked users from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, db2, database-administration

I have a sql server database that uses linked server concept to connect to DB2 database. The DB2 database has read access only. I need to check every day whether the Db2 user is locked or not (due to incorrect password entered more than three times) from SQL Server. Once this is checked I can probably send an email to set of users about the status of the DB2 user (locked or unlocked)

How I can implement this feature? I am aware about SQL Server "loginproperty" concept that checks whether the user (using SQL Server Authentication) is locked out or not.

Thanks,

Comment: Any comments will  be of much help

Answer (score 1):

DB2 does not do user authentication -- the task is delegated to the operating system (or LDAP, if so configured). Therefore you will need to get the locked account information from that external authority (OS or LDAP), not DB2.

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio... Yes LDAP is configured...Moreover, Is it possible to get information if the creator name is locked out or not?

Comment: Most LDAP servers allow you to run a query against them; the property to search for is `pwdAccountLockedTime` I believe.

Comment: So I guess there is no way of knowing if I can find out from SQL Server that if a DB2 creator ID is locked out or not..?

Answer (score 1):

Query the remote table.  If you get an error [`SQL30082N`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql30082n.html), the account is locked.

Comment: Do you have DB2 query that checks for user account status (locked/unlocked)?

Comment: `select * from <linked_table> where 1=0` ?  You're just trying to force MSSQL to make a connection to the database via the query.  You don't need any data, thus the odd where clause.

Comment: Can you help me find out the syntax for the logic you have mentioned in above comments? I am struggling here a bit

Comment: Execute the query I gave you, but replace `<linked_table>` with the actual name of the linked table.